# saving time to database

Tags: c#, sql, web-services, webmethod

I am trying to save date and time that is in a form label to the database. How to convert string to System.date time

```
Attendance record = new Attendance();
record.Date = lbDate.Text;
record.Time = lbTime.Text;
```

Comment: what is the format of your date?

Comment: HAve you looked at [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

if your date is in format of `dd/MM/yyyy`

Try This:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(datetime ,"dd/MM/yyyy",
                                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Now you can assign `dt` to the `datetime` type of your database parameter.

```
Attendance record = new Attendance();
record.Date = dt.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
record.Time = lbTime.Text;
```

Comment: Don't forget to include the parsing of the time in your answer ;-)

Comment: Data type for Date in the sql is Date and time Time. I only like to save the date dd/mm/yyyy and time as hh:mm:ss

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: i am using sql server. I have a date that is displayed in my form as lbDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString(); and time as lbTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();